# calling a script function using requests_html python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm looking to scrape some data from the following web site: https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/stats-centre/archive/2022/414/MS024

The underlying match statistics are loaded by the following javacript:

```
<script nonce="5e824960-ee11-4894-b33c-9b0a25ace2d3" type="text/javascript">
        var initial = {
            matchStatsContainer : "#matchStatsContainer",
            matchStatsTemplate : "#matchStatsTemplate",
            currentMatchStatsToggle : "currentMatchStatsButton",
            liveMatchUrl : "",
            setPhrase : "set",
            matchPhrase : "match",
            liveMatchDetails : {
                isMatchLive : 'True',
                eventId : '414',
                matchId : 'MS024'
            }

        }
        require(["modules/modal/modalScoresMatchStats"],
            function (ModalScoresMatchStats) {
                return new ModalScoresMatchStats({
                    matchStatsContainer : "#match-stats-container",
                    matchStatsTemplate : "#matchStatsTemplate",
                    currentMatchStatsToggle : "currentMatchStatsButton",
                    liveMatchUrl : "",
                    setPhrase : "set",
                    matchPhrase : "match",
                    liveMatchDetails : {
                        isMatchLive : 'True',
                        eventId : '414',
                        matchId : 'MS024'
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

I am using the following code with script set to:

```
 var initial = { .....
      liveMatchDetails : {
                        isMatchLive : 'True',
                        eventId : '414',
                        matchId : 'MS024'
                    }
                });
            });



html = HTML(html=str(match_stats_html), async_=True)
val = html.render(script=script, reload=False)
```

I get the following error:

ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: require is not defined
at **pyppeteer_evaluation_script**:16:9

When I remove require from the script I get the following error:

ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Any ideas on how  I could execute the script and obtain the data returned by the results?

Thanks

Comment: That script was not actually delivered to a browser, was it?  `require` is a node.js concept that is not present in Javascript, and is not implemented in browsers.  Javascript in the browser doesn't have access to a file system, so it can't load modules.

Comment: Requests-html is using Pypeteer in the background for loading and executing scripts. Might as well use selenium for this task, straight-forward. That page also serves info via a socket, so you might look into it as well.

Comment: I see the page actually loads a package called `"require.js"` that must load the modules from a back-end somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

r = scraper.get('https://www.atptour.com/-/ajax/Scores/GetInitialScores')
print(r.json())
```

This returns:

```
{'liveScores': {'Tournaments': [{'EventYear': 2022, 'Name': 'Hamburg European Open', 'EventId': '414', 'TournamentLink': '/en/tournaments/hamburg/414/overview', 'OfficialWebsite': 'www.hamburg-open.com', 'Location': 'Hamburg, Germany', 'TournamentBadgeImage': '/-/media/images/tourtypes/categorystamps_500_118x136.png?sc=0&hash=7431FC4DF8556F6BB9AA56E8578D5342', 'LiveScoresLinkText': 'Scores', 'LiveScoresLink': '/en/scores/current/hamburg/414/live-scores', 'DrawLinkText': 'Draw', 'DrawLink': '/en/scores/current/hamburg/414/draws', 'ScheduleLinkText': 'Schedule', 'ScheduleLink': '/en/scores/current/hamburg/414/daily-schedule', 'H2HLinkText': 'H2H', 'StatsLinkText': 'Stats', 'PlayNotStarted': '#Play Not Started Yet#', 'TournamentPosition': '1', 'IsLaverCup': False, 'Matches': [{'Id': 'MS008', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 415, 'EventId': '414', 'RoundTitle': 'Round of 16 - Center Court', 'MatchType': 'singles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/414/MS008', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/c-alcaraz-vs-f-krajinovic/A0E2/KB05', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/414/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 1, 'LiveListingPosition': 1, 'Status': 'F', 'Winner': '2', 'LastServer': None, 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '01:52:54', 'MatchInfo': 'Game Set and Match Carlos Alcaraz. \r\n Carlos Alcaraz wins the match  7-6(4) 6-3 .', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'A0E2', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'C.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Alcaraz', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'ESP', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'C. Alcaraz', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Carlos-Alcaraz', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ESP.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/carlos-alcaraz/a0e2/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/A0E2', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'won-game', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '7', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '6', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'KB05', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'F.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Krajinovic', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'SRB', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'F. Krajinovic', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Filip-Krajinovic', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/SRB.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/filip-krajinovic/kb05/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/KB05', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': '4', 'SetTwo': '3', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}, {'Id': 'MS015', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 384, 'EventId': '414', 'RoundTitle': 'Round of 16 - Center Court', 'MatchType': 'singles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/414/MS015', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/f-cerundolo-vs-a-rublev/C0AU/RE44', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/414/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 2, 'LiveListingPosition': None, 'Status': 'F', 'Winner': '2', 'LastServer': None, 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '01:32:08', 'MatchInfo': 'Game Set and Match Francisco Cerundolo. \r\n Francisco Cerundolo wins the match  6-4  6-2 .', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'C0AU', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'F.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Cerundolo', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'ARG', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'F. Cerundolo', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Francisco-Cerundolo', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ARG.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/francisco-cerundolo/c0au/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/C0AU', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'won-game', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '6', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'RE44', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'A.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Rublev', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'RUS', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'A. Rublev', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Andrey-Rublev', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/RUS.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/andrey-rublev/re44/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/RE44', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '4', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '2', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}, {'Id': 'MS009', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 384, 'EventId': '414', 'RoundTitle': 'Round of 16 - Center Court', 'MatchType': 'singles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/414/MS009', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/f-fognini-vs-k-khachanov/F510/KE29', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/414/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 3, 'LiveListingPosition': None, 'Status': 'F', 'Winner': '3', 'LastServer': None, 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '01:42:52', 'MatchInfo': 'Game Set and Match Karen Khachanov. \r\n Karen Khachanov wins the match  6-3  7-5 .', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'F510', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'F.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Fognini', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'ITA', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'F. Fognini', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Fabio-Fognini', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ITA.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/fabio-fognini/f510/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/F510', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '3', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '5', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'KE29', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'K.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Khachanov', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'RUS', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'K. Khachanov', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Karen-Khachanov', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/RUS.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/karen-khachanov/ke29/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/KE29', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'won-game', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '7', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}]}, {'EventYear': 2022, 'Name': 'EFG Swiss Open Gstaad', 'EventId': '314', 'TournamentLink': '/en/tournaments/gstaad/314/overview', 'OfficialWebsite': 'swissopengstaad.ch', 'Location': 'Gstaad, Switzerland', 'TournamentBadgeImage': '/-/media/images/tourtypes/categorystamps_250_118x136.png?sc=0&hash=10547153B5ADD7DCF2E0C8DAA42886EE', 'LiveScoresLinkText': 'Scores', 'LiveScoresLink': '/en/scores/current/gstaad/314/live-scores', 'DrawLinkText': 'Draw', 'DrawLink': '/en/scores/current/gstaad/314/draws', 'ScheduleLinkText': 'Schedule', 'ScheduleLink': '/en/scores/current/gstaad/314/daily-schedule', 'H2HLinkText': 'H2H', 'StatsLinkText': 'Stats', 'PlayNotStarted': '#Play Not Started Yet#', 'TournamentPosition': '2', 'IsLaverCup': False, 'Matches': [{'Id': 'MD007', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 218, 'EventId': '314', 'RoundTitle': 'Quarterfinal - Court 1', 'MatchType': 'doubles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/314/MD007', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/l-sonego-vs-r-jebavy/SU87/J321', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/314/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 1, 'LiveListingPosition': 1, 'Status': 'P', 'Winner': '0', 'LastServer': '0', 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '00:45:31', 'MatchInfo': 'L. Sonego/A. Vavassori win the point on the 1st serve of L. Sonego.', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'SU87', 'PartnerId': 'VA08', 'PlayerFirstName': 'L.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Sonego', 'PartnerFirstName': 'A.', 'PartnerLastName': 'Vavassori', 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'ITA', 'PartnerCountryCode': 'ITA', 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'L. Sonego', 'PartnerNameForUrl': 'Andrea-Vavassori', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Lorenzo-Sonego', 'PlayerTwoName': 'A. Vavassori', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ITA.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ITA.svg', 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/lorenzo-sonego/su87/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': '/en/players/andrea-vavassori/va08/overview', 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/SU87', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/VA08', 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'now-serving', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': '30', 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '3', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'J321', 'PartnerId': 'O474', 'PlayerFirstName': 'R.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Jebavy', 'PartnerFirstName': 'J.', 'PartnerLastName': "O'Mara", 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'CZE', 'PartnerCountryCode': 'GBR', 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'R. Jebavy', 'PartnerNameForUrl': "Jonny-O'Mara", 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Roman-Jebavy', 'PlayerTwoName': "J. O'Mara", 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/CZE.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/GBR.svg', 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/roman-jebavy/j321/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': "/en/players/jonny-o'mara/o474/overview", 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/J321', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/O474', 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': '0', 'SetOne': '2', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '1', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}, {'Id': 'MS008', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 432, 'EventId': '314', 'RoundTitle': 'Round of 16 - Roy Emerson Arena', 'MatchType': 'singles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/314/MS008', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/c-ruud-vs-j-lehecka/RH16/L0BV', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/314/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 2, 'LiveListingPosition': None, 'Status': 'F', 'Winner': '2', 'LastServer': None, 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '01:39:31', 'MatchInfo': 'Game Set and Match Casper Ruud. \r\n Casper Ruud wins the match  6-3  6-4 .', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'RH16', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'C.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Ruud', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'NOR', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'C. Ruud', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Casper-Ruud', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/NOR.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/casper-ruud/rh16/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/RH16', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'won-game', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '6', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'L0BV', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'J.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Lehecka', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'CZE', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'J. Lehecka', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Jiri-Lehecka', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/CZE.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/jiri-lehecka/l0bv/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/L0BV', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '3', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '4', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}, {'Id': 'MS015', 'ChallengerTVMatchItemId': '', 'KSeq': 374, 'EventId': '314', 'RoundTitle': 'Round of 16 - Roy Emerson Arena', 'MatchType': 'singles', 'StatsLink': 'en/scores/stats-centre/live/2022/314/MS015', 'HeadToHeadLink': '/en/players/atp-head-2-head/r-gasquet-vs-m-berrettini/G628/BK40', 'SecondScreenLink': '', 'ChallengerTVLink': '/en/atp-challenger-tour/challenger-tv/challenger-tv-search-results//2022/314/all', 'TeamTieStatsLink': '', 'RailPosition': 3, 'LiveListingPosition': None, 'Status': 'F', 'Winner': '3', 'LastServer': None, 'NumberOfSets': 3, 'MatchTime': '01:29:29', 'MatchInfo': 'Game Set and Match Matteo Berrettini. \r\n Matteo Berrettini wins the match  6-4  6-4 .', 'TeamTieResults': {'RoundRobinGroupNumber': 0, 'RoundRobinGroupName': None, 'RoundRobinCityName': None, 'TeamCountryCode': None, 'OpponentTeamCountryCode': None, 'TeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'OpponentTeamTieMatchWins': 0, 'TotalTieMatchesPlayed': 0, 'TeamCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'OpponentCountryFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ghost-flag.svg', 'HasTeamTieStats': False, 'IsRoundRobin': False}, 'TeamOne': {'PlayerId': 'G628', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'R.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Gasquet', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'FRA', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'R. Gasquet', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Richard-Gasquet', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/FRA.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/richard-gasquet/g628/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/G628', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': '', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '4', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '4', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'TeamTwo': {'PlayerId': 'BK40', 'PartnerId': None, 'PlayerFirstName': 'M.', 'PlayerLastName': 'Berrettini', 'PartnerFirstName': '', 'PartnerLastName': None, 'PlayerSeed': None, 'PlayerEntryType': None, 'PlayerCountryCode': 'ITA', 'PartnerCountryCode': None, 'PartnerSeed': None, 'PartnerEntryType': None, 'GamePointsPlayerTeam': None, 'PlayerOneName': 'M. Berrettini', 'PartnerNameForUrl': '', 'PlayerNameForUrl': 'Matteo-Berrettini', 'PlayerTwoName': ' ', 'PlayerOneFlag': '/en/~/media/images/flags/ITA.svg', 'PlayerTwoFlag': None, 'PlayerOneLink': '/en/players/matteo-berrettini/bk40/overview', 'PlayerTwoLink': None, 'PlayerOneHeadshot': '/-/media/alias/player-headshot/BK40', 'PlayerTwoHeadshot': None, 'TeamSeed': None, 'TeamEntryType': None, 'TeamStatus': 'won-game', 'Scores': {'CurrentScore': None, 'SetOne': '6', 'SetOneTiebreak': None, 'SetTwo': '6', 'SetTwoTiebreak': None, 'SetThree': None, 'SetThreeTiebreak': None, 'SetFour': None, 'SetFourTiebreak': None, 'SetFive': None, 'SetFiveTiebreak': None}}, 'IsWatchLive': False, 'HasHawkeyeData': False, 'HasStats': True, 'HasHead2Head': True, 'HasChallengerTVWeb': False}]}]}}
```

​
cloudscraper can be installed with `pip install cloudscraper`

Comment: I hae a question, how did you get to know that URL?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar from Network tab.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 thanks, now I just need to figure out how to query completed matches vs. live matches. If you have any thoughts, I would appreciate it.